# Building a custom test slice for Spring Retry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As the title says, I am trying to build a test slice for testing a method annotated with [@Retryable](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry). I know that I can create a test using `@SpringBootTest` or some other such extremely wide-net annotation for starting up a full context, but I was hoping to narrow the spring context down so it initializes only the beans it needs to initialize to speed up the test (and learn a bit about Spring custom test slices in the process).

I started by creating a new `@RetryTest` annotation

```java
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@BootstrapWith(DefaultTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ExtendWith({ SpringExtension.class })
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@TypeExcludeFilters(RetryTypeExcludeFilter.class)
public @interface RetryTest {
    @AliasFor("classes")
    Class<?>[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor("value")
    Class<?>[] classes() default {};
}
```

with a new `TypeExcludeFilter`

```java
public final class RetryTypeExcludeFilter extends StandardAnnotationCustomizableTypeExcludeFilter<RetryTest> {

    private static final Class<?>[] NO_CLASSES = new Class[0];
    private static final Set<Class<?>> DEFAULT_INCLUDES;
    private final Class<?>[] classes;

    RetryTypeExcludeFilter(Class<?> testClass) {
        super(testClass);
        this.classes = (Class<?>[]) this.getAnnotation().getValue("classes", Class[].class).orElse(NO_CLASSES);
    }

    protected Set<Class<?>> getDefaultIncludes() {
        return DEFAULT_INCLUDES;
    }

    protected Set<Class<?>> getComponentIncludes() {
        return new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(this.classes));
    }

    static {
        Set<Class<?>> includes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        includes.add(EnableRetry.class);

        DEFAULT_INCLUDES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(includes);
    }
}
```

This filter was mainly copied from `WebMvcTypeExcludeFilter`. I liked the idea that you could specify the exact controller that you wanted to instantiate as a bean, but then I changed that to allow me to specify the class under test.

The test class itself is very simple, and currently looks like this:

```java
@RetryTest({ ClassUnderTest.class })
class ClassUnderTestTest {

    @Autowired
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @Test
    void executeFunction_test() {
        Runnable runnable = mock(Runnable.class);
        doThrow(new RuntimeException("Error message")).when(runnable).run();

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> classUnderTest.executeFunction(runnable, "Error message"))
            .isInstanceOf(CustomException.class);

        verify(runnable, times(3)).run();
    }
}
```

and the actual class under test looks like this:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClassUnderTest {

    @Retryable(retryFor = { RuntimeException.class })
    public <T> T executeFunction(Runnable functionCall, String errorDetails) {
        return functionCall.run();
    }

    @Recover
    public <T> T executeAWSCall(RuntimeException e, Runnable functionCall, String errorDetails) {
        throw new CustomException(e, errorDetails);
    }
}
```

However, I'm still finding that this isn't working. The test runs, but it's not running with a spring context and so the retry is not triggering (I can tell, because the exception is of type `RuntimeException` instead of `CustomException`).

There are three places I am mostly looking looking at as potential sources of the issue:

1. `getDefaultIncludes` in the `RetryTypeExcludeFilter`. I frankly have no idea when this is invoked in the lifecycle or how it is used, and I definitely don't know what I should be including in it.
2. `@BootstrapWith` - I'm currently using a default test context because I couldn't really see anything in the WebMvcContext that was of value for retry or that looked like it would be necessary. But again, I'm not really sure what this does, or if it's needed at all.
3. AutoConfiguration. A lot of the pre-built test slices use autoconfiguration and `@ImportAutoConfiguration` as a way of specifying beans to instantiate. However, I have no idea what beans I would need to instantiate to get this working, so currently I am not specifying any, or invoking any existing autoconfigurations.

Answer (score 1):

##### 1. `getDefaultIncludes` in the `RetryTypeExcludeFilter`:

This method is great for ensuring that specific classes are always  included in your Spring ApplicationContext for your tests, regaurdless of other exclusion filters. Also, you've added `EnableRetry.class` to your default includes, which is great, but (iirc) `EnableRetry` itself is not a class, but an annotation. So you would use `@EnableRetry` in you ApplicationContext, it's usually best on a [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) class like so:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
pub class RetryConfig {
  // config
}
```

just make sure this class is included in your slice either with the `classes` attribute, or by with your `getDefaultIncludes` method.

##### 2. `@BootstrapWith`

`@BootstrapWith` allows you to customize the way your Spring test context is initialized. Normally, sticking with the `DefaultTestContextBootstrapper` works fine for the average test.but since you are writing a custom test slice, you want to ensure that everything needed for retries is correctly set up from the start.

If you don't think you need to make a custom bootstrapper, that's great, plus, in most cases involving retries, the default should suffice. Just make sure your test context includes the necessary retry configurations. (i.e., you'd need a @Configuration class with @EnableRetry on it.)

##### 3. AutoConfiguration

AutoConfiguration automatically configures your application based on the classes available on the classpath. For your custom slice, it might be good to explicitly specify which auto-configuration classes are relevant in your context, especially if you're disabling overall auto-configuration.

##### A Small Example

write your configuration class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class RetryConfig {
  // config to enable Spring Retry
  // usually a RetryTemplate, since it's the main class 
  // that covers both the retry and backoff policies
  @Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);

    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000L); // 1000ms delay between retries

    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    return retryTemplate;
  }
}
```

then you would make sure your test imports this config

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@BootstrapWith(DefaultTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@TypeExcludeFilters(RetryTypeExcludeFilter.class)
@Import(RetryConfig.class) // this guy here
public @interface RetryTest {
  @AliasFor("classes")
  Class<?>[] value() default {};

  @AliasFor("value")
    Class<?>[] classes() default {};
}
```

lastly, in your `ClassUnderTest` you would apply your `@RetryTest` annotation specifying both the `ClassUnderTest.class` as well as the `RetryConfig.class`

```java
@RetryTest({ ClassUnderTest.class, RetryConfig.class})
class ClassUnderTestTest {
  // same as you did
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so it seems like the big difference here is just ensuring that the configuration class annotated with `@EnableRetry` is imported. I've made the changes as you suggest, but it doesn't look like spring is instantiating the ClassUnderTest bean, as when I try to autowire it in I get a "no autowire candidates" question.

Comment: @EaterOfFromage I think the problem is stemming from `@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)`, which causes Spring to not automatically pick up components based on it's package scanning. Auto-configuration is pretty smart, and backs off as you define more of your own configuaration, so it may be a good idea to keep it on. Otherwise, you can explicitly import or define the bean in your `@configuration`.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html